# Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.oracleucp.s-s-l-context.provider'

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, java-17

I ma facing the issue while migrating the hava 11 to 17 and spring boot to 3.0 and spring web 6.

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.oracleucp.s-s-l-context.provider' to java.security.Provider:

```
Reason: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.security.Provider.<init>()
```

Action:

Update your application's configuration

Comment: Any news on that issue? I'am facing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This seems that may be you have not added the following properties in application.properties file add also your may be facing this issue because in spring security version which you are using with sring-3 is not compatible with spring-6   for more information read this [https://spring.io/blog/2022/11/21/spring-security-5-8-and-6-0-are-now-ga#:~:text=Spring%20Security%206%20requires%20JDK%2017%20and%20uses%20the%20jakarta%20namespace](https://spring.io/blog/2022/11/21/spring-security-5-8-and-6-0-are-now-ga#:%7E:text=Spring%20Security%206%20requires%20JDK%2017%20and%20uses%20the%20jakarta%20namespace).

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=upate
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin1234
```

Comment: I have already configured above properties. And also i am using the oracle database not mysql

Comment: Not sure how the oracleucp is working internally, this oracleucp is connection pooling service like Hikari CP. We have some issues with Hicari CP that's why using the Oracle UCP.

Answer (score 0):

This property: **'spring.datasource.oracleucp.s-s-l-context.provider'** is not defined in the current spring boot documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html.

We found out, that by removing the datasource property **'spring.datasource.type'** the application is running again. If you are not using Connection Pools, you may remove thatproperty. Otherwise read the documentation:

[https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/data.html#data.sql.datasource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/data.html#data.sql.datasource%C2%A0)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue in SpringBoot:

[Spring boot fails to create data source bean when using UCP and JndiPropertySource is enabled. #38514](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38514)

And it's fixed in SpringBoot 3.2.